# Can't get to delete rows from my ListView

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to delete a row by clicking on it but it does not delete it.

This is my `DataListActivity`

```
package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DataListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DatabaseClass  database;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
        database = new DatabaseClass(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = database.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
        do {

            String id,product_name,category;
            id= cursor.getString(0);
            product_name=cursor.getString(1);
            category=cursor.getString(2);
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(id,product_name,category);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_id);
        DatabaseClass.DeleteInformation(tv.getText().toString(),sqLiteDatabase);
        listDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

This is `DataProvider` class
    package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

```
/**
 * Created by family on 10/08/2016.
 */
public class DataProvider {

    private String id;
    private String product_name;
    private String category;

    public DataProvider(String id,String product_name,String category)
    {
    this.id = id;
    this.product_name=product_name;
    this.category=category;

    }
        public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }
}
```

This is my `Database` class

```
package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

/**
 * Created by family on 06/07/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_Name = "Product.db2";
    public static final String Table_Name = "product_table2";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Quantity";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Category";
    public static final String COL_5 = "Importance";
    public DatabaseClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_Name, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + Table_Name + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,Quantity TEXT,Category INTEGER,Importance TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exists" + Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String quantity, String category,String importance) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);

        long result = db.insert(Table_Name, null, contentValues);

            if (result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Table_Name, null);
        return res;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id,String name,String quantity,String category,String importance ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);
        db.update(Table_Name,contentValues,"id =?",new String[]{id});
                return true;
    }

   /* public Cursor getCursor(){
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        queryBuilder.setR
    }
*/
   public Integer DeleteData (String id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       return db.delete(Table_Name,"ID = ?",new String[]{id});
   }
    public static void DeleteInformation(String item_name,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){

        String selection = COL_1+" LIKE ?";
        String [] selection_args = {item_name};
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(Table_Name,selection,selection_args);

    }

    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        Cursor cursor;
        String [] Projections = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_4};

        cursor  = sqLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name,Projections,null,null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }

    public Cursor getItem(String item_name ,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        String [] Projections = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5};
        String selection = COL_1+" LIKE ?";
        String [] selection_args = {item_name};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name,Projections,selection,selection_args,null,null,null);
        return cursor;

    }
```

*ListDataAdapter *

```
package ie.example.artur.projectrepeat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by family on 10/08/2016.
 */
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  {
   List list = new ArrayList ();

    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }





    static class LayoutHandler
    {
        TextView id,product_name,category;

    }
    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();

    }



    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_id);
            layoutHandler.product_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            layoutHandler.category = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_category);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();

        }
        DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.id.setText(dataProvider.getId());
        layoutHandler.product_name.setText(dataProvider.getProduct_name());
        layoutHandler.category.setText(dataProvider.getCategory());



        return row;




    }


    }




     }
```

Comment: Your `DatabaseClass.DeleteInformation(tv.getText().toString());` is missing `SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase` as a second parameter. Did you consider that?

Comment: I got to run my program but when I click on the rows it doesn't delete any of them

Comment: You should delete selected row from SQLite Db and then pass new data set to adapter. Then call notifyDateSetChanged. When you delete row only in Db the adapter is not aware of row being deleted. The key is to update the data you have passed to adapter too.

Comment: I have notifyDateSetChanged ,there's still no change .What do you mean delete the selected row?

Comment: First of all you need to `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` to your `DeleteInformation()` method. What about the notify, it is hard to say something confidently without your adapter code. But the main idea is given in the previous comment. Adapter needs to be aware that you have deleted the information in sqlite db. For instance, if you are passing your data as List, Array, or any other way, you need to update that holder when you delete item and then pass it again to your adapter.

Comment: When I put `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` into`DeleteInformation()` it says it cannot be referenced from a static context.And about the notify ,once I have it implemented it will automatically  update the adapter ,or is there anything else I have to add so it is updated?

Comment: I have a posted the ListDataAdapter ,could you please have a look at it ,maybe there is a problem in there?